What Is The Meaning of Psalm 111:9?
Good evening,
Psalm 111:9 has yielded some awkward phrasing in English translations that makes it hard to decipher the meaning of the verse, particularly the part about the covenant:

“He sent redemption to his people; he has commanded his covenant
forever. Holy and awesome is his name!” ‭‭Psalm‬ ‭111‬:‭9‬ ‭ESV‬‬
“He has sent redemption to His people; He has commanded His covenant
forever: Holy and awesome is His name.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭111‬:‭9‬ ‭NKJV‬‬
“He provided redemption for his people; he ordained his covenant
forever— holy and awesome is his name.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭111‬:‭9‬ ‭NIV‬‬

What exactly does it mean for God to command or ordain His covenant? Is there maybe a better rendering of the Hebrew that provides a more coherent reading in English?
Furthermore, through cross-referencing it appears the word for “redemption” can mean “ransom” in other contexts. Do we have any information from historical background of the Psalm to ascertain what exact redemption or ransom is being referenced?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Ordain: to establish or order by appointment, decree, or law
The word in question is usually translated as "command," but in English this is awkward because commands are issued to a person that responds by obeying. Technically you cannot command a covenant in which way. So to command a covenant requires reading something into the sentence: namely that God establishes a covenant between himself and Israel. But you can indeed "ordain" a covenant. Thus some translators prefer "ordain."
Regarding redemption, to redeem something is to buy it back. This explains why some translators say "ransom." The historical background depends on when one thinks the psalm was written. If it is post-exilic, the poet may have God's redeeming Israel from bondage in Babylon in mind but a more spiritual sense of redemption is also possible.

In the OT there are five covenants as follows:

Noahide Covenant: Gen 8:20 – 9:17
Abrahamic Covenant: Gen 12:1-3, 13:14-17, 15:1-17, 17:1-27, 18:9-15, 22:15-18
Israelite Covenant: Exodus 19-24, and expanded in parts of Leviticus, Numbers and Deuteronomy – often called, “The Old Covenant”, or, “Moral Covenant”
Levitical Covenant: – Lev 1-9, 16, 21-27 , Num 3, 4, 8, 18, 25:10-13, Deut 33:8-11, Neh 13:29, Mal 2:4-8. This is an eternal covenant (Num 25:12, 13, Ps 106:30, Jer 33:18, 21, 22) of salt, Num 18:19
Davidic (or Regal, or Royal) Covenant: 2 Sam 7, 23:5, 1 Kings 6:11, 12, 8:25, 1 Chron 17:11-14, 2 Chron 6:14-16, 7:17, 18, 13:5, Ps 89:4, 29, 34, 39, 132:11, 12, Jer 33:17, 21, Eze 37:15-28.  This is an eternal covenant; 2 Sam 23:5, 1 Kings 9:5, 2 Chron 13:5, Eze 37:25, 26, Jer 33:17, 21 or salt, 2 Chron 13:5.

All of these were initiated by God and offer the recipients a series of benefits/blessings along with an associated series of responsibilities.  These covenants were ordained and initiated by God and the promises/blessings they contained be completely dependent upon God keeping those promises
In Ps 111:9 the referenced covenant is almost certainly the Israelite covenant (#3 above) which is eternal, 1 Chron 16:17, Jer 50:5, Ps 105:8, 111:5, 9.  Thus, given that this covenant was initiated by God, it is entirely expected that it was concomitantly ordained by God precisely as this verse states.
APPENDIX - The Israelite Covenant
In Ex 19 Moses is instructed in the Covenant directly by God.  Moses then conveys the content of the covenant to the people which is recorded in Ex 20:1-17 as the 10 Commandments, and then explained and amplified in Ex 20:22-23:33.  The people answered, three times, “whatever the Lord has said we will do”, Ex 19:8, 24:3, 7, thus creating the Israelite covenant.  [Later they rejected the Covenant and a New Covenant had to be instituted with Christians with the same content.]  This Covenant was open to all people from its inception and was voluntary.  See “Israel”.
This Israelite Covenant consisted of the following:

God promises to “save” Israel from Egyptian slavery and deliver them to the Promised Land as stated in the preamble to the 10 commandments, Ex 20:1, 2, 23:23, Deut 5:6.  This was to fulfil God’s earlier promise to Abraham and others to give the Promised Land to Abraham’s descendants, Ex 2:24, 6:4, 5, forever, 1 Chron 16:15, Ps 105:8, 111:9.
God promises to protect His people by sending a protecting angel, Ex 23:19, 20, and establish their borders, Ex 23:31.
The benefits/promises of the covenant are also clearly set out in Lev 26:1-13, Deut 28:1-14 (blessings for obedience), and, Lev 26:14-39, Deut 28:15-68 (curses for disobedience). [Note that the curses for disobedience are specifically listed in Lev 26 as plague (V14-17), famine (V18-20), wild animals (V21, 22), sword/war (V23-26).  Subsequently, these curses for disobedience are simply listed as “sword, famine and plague” in many places such as 1 Chron 21:12, 2 Chron 20:9, Jer 21:9, 24:10, 27:13, 29:18, 42:22, Eze 5:12, 17, 7:15, 12:16, etc, etc.  The same is repeated in the first four seals of Rev 6.]
The purpose the Covenant (Ex 20:1-17) is stated clearly in Ex 19:5, 6 – to make the Israelites God’s peculiar treasure, his special people, distinguished by the way they conducted themselves.  Ps 50:16-18, 74:20, 78:36, 37.
This purpose of the covenant was stated in other ways as, “I will take you as my own people, and I will be your God. Then you will know that I am the LORD your God, … ” Ex 6:7.  This is stated repeatedly: Lev 26:9-12, Deut 29:9-13, 2 Sam 7:24, 1 Chron 11:2, Ps 50:7, 95:7, 100:3, Isa 40:1, Jer 7:23, 11:1-4, 24:7, 30:9, 22, 31:1, 33, 32:38-40, Eze 11:20, 34:30, 31, 36:26-28, 37:23, 24, Hos 1:9, 4:6, Joel 2:26, 27, Zech 8:8.  It is significant that the first of the 10 Commandments is a decree to have only ONE God, the LORD, Ex 20:3, Deut, 5:7, 6:4-6.

This same idea is also expressed another way – creating a people who would be “called by the name of the LORD”, or, “called by my name”, 2 Chron 7:14, Isa 43:7, 65:1; that is, to bear the character of a gracious, loving, kind God.  The Jerusalem Temple was also a symbol of this covenant because it was “called by my Name”, 1 Kings 8:13, Jer 7:10, 11, 14, 32:34, 34:15.  Such people, God declared, “out of all nations you will be my treasured possession … a kingdom of priests and a holy nation.” Ex 19:5, 6.  See also Ruth 1:16.
Significantly, in Eze 36:16-38, the LORD sternly rebukes Israel because, “they profaned My holy name, because it was said of them, ‘These are the people of the LORD, yet they had to leave His land.’  But I had concern for My holy name, which the house of Israel had profaned among the nations to which they had gone. (v22, 23).  That is, Israel had profaned the name of God by sinning.

The requirements of the Israelite covenant are the 10 Commandments as recorded on the tablets of stone and amplified in Ex 20:22-23:33, the book of Deuteronomy and elsewhere such as Lev 17-19, 26.  This is shown by the following facts:


Ex 24:7 introduces the “Book of the Covenant” (which see) as already existing, ie, Ex 20:22 – 23:33.  It served as an expansion and legal context in which to place the Israelite Covenant of the 10 Commandments.




These tablets of stone with the 10 Commandments are called “the covenant” (Ex 34:27, 28, Deut 9:9, 11, 15) and placed inside the ark (Ex 25:16, 21, 40:20, Heb 9:4).  [The tables of stone were also called “the tables of Testimony” (Ex 31:18, 32:15, 34:29), or just, “The Testimony” (Ex 25:16, 21).]




The “Ark of the Covenant” (Num 10:33, 14:44, Deut 10:8, 31:9, 25, 26, Josh 3:3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, 4:7, 9, 18, 6:6, 8:33, etc) or, “Ark of the Testimony” (Ex 25:22, 26:33, 34, 30:6, 26, 31:7, 39:35, 40:3, 5, 21, Lev 16:13, Num 4:5, 7:89, Josh 4:16, etc) is described thus precisely because it contained the stone tablets inscribed by the finger of God (Ex 31:18, Deut 9:10) with the Israelite Covenant of the 10 Commandments.  1 Kings 8:9, 2 Chron 5:10.




The ancient sacred “Tabernacle”, also known as the “tent of meeting” (Ex 39:32, 40:2, 6, 22, 24, 35, Lev 17:4, Num 3:7, 8, 4:25, 31) was also called the “tent of covenant law” (Num 9:15, 1:50, 53, Ex 38:21) because it housed the Ark of the Covenant containing the Covenant Law.




The re-statement and expansion of the 10 Commandments as the covenant in Deut 4:13, 23, 31, 5:2, 3 includes a reference back to the Covenant at Horeb, ie, Mt Sinai (See Ex 3:1, 17:6, 33:6, etc, and the statement of the covenant in Ex 19, 20, and restated in Ex 24).




The 10 Commandments Covenant is distinct from the Levitical law and Davidic Covenant.


The visible symbols of the Israelite Covenant solemnity and importance included: an altar of 12 stones (Ex 24:4), a sacrifice (Ex 24:5), sprinkled blood of the covenant (Ex 24:8).  The blood of the covenant was used dramatically when painted on the door posts in Egypt at the first Passover (Ex 12).
The tokens/signs of the covenant (Heb: “oth”) appear to have been the law of the 10 Commandments themselves (Deut 6:8, 11:18), and especially the Sabbath (Ex 31:13, 16, 17, Isa 56:4, 6, Exe 20:12, 20, see “Sabbath”); the blood of the covenant from the Passover Lamb is also used as a sign in Ex 12:13; the famous “Ark of the Covenant” containing the 10 Commandments on tablets of stone (Ex 16:34, 24:12, 25:16, 21, 31:18, 32:15, 19, 34:1, 4, 28, 40:20, Deut 4:13, 9-11, etc).  [Note: This did not include circumcision as this was a sign of the Abrahamic covenant to which the Israelites fell heirs.]
Lev 26:44, 45, Ps 105:8, 111:5, 9, Jer 31:35-37, 32, 40, 33:25 declare the Israelite covenant immutable, irrevocable and eternal. See also Heb 13:20, 1 Chron 16:15, 17, Jer 50:5, Ps 105:8, Eze 37:26.

That this Israelite Covenant was a covenant of transforming grace is confirmed by several ideas:

The Israelite Covenant was a covenant initiated entirely by God alone, to save Israel.  God alone set out the requirements and blessings.  God makes it clear that they were selected as the chosen people, NOT because of any Israelite merit, but simply because God wanted to.  Deut 7:7, 9:5, 6, 10:15.
The Israelite/old Covenant was a matter of the “heart” (Deut 6:5, 10:12, 16, 11:18, Ps 40:8, Jer 24:7, 31:33, 34, 32:38-40, Eze 11:19, 18:31, 36:26) and NOT mere regulations (1 Sam 15:22, Ps 40:6-8, 51:16, 17, Prov 15:8, 21:3, Isa 1:10-17, Jer 6:3-6, 20, Hos 6:6, Micah 6:6-8).  These references make it clear that the Old Covenant did not really include the animal sacrifices, and that they could not define nor atone for sin. (Heb 9:9, 10:4, Ps 51:16, 17, 1 Sam 15:22).  The animal sacrifices and the sanctuary ritual were part of the Levitical covenant which acted as teaching device that anticipated, and was a type of, the High Priestly ministry of Messiah.
The Ark of the Covenant, containing the Covenant stone tablets of the 10 Commandments, was constructed in a highly symbolic way.  The 10 Commandments were inside the box and the “atonement cover” or “mercy seat” was placed above them.  Ex 25:17-22, 26:34, 30:6, 31:17, 37:9, 40:20, Lev 16:13; see also Heb 9:5.  This arrangement was placed in the Most Holy Place, in the sanctuary, and always remained at the center of God’s Covenant people.
In Solomon’s prayer of dedication, he describes the (Israelite) Covenant as God showing “lovingkindness”, or, “steadfast love”, to people.  1 Kings 8:23, 2 Chron 6:14, See also Neh 1:5, 9:32, Ps 89:28, 33, 34, 103:17, 18, 111:4, 5, 9, Isa 54:10, 55:3.  This suggests that the Law of God, or the Moral Law, is an expression of God’s love and is just as eternal.

Many moderns suggest that the old Israelite covenant was a “law of works” and thus distinct from the “law of love” under the new covenant. This is simply untrue as is obvious from its own declarations and those of Jesus Himself! Note the following:

Lev 19:18 - Do not seek revenge or bear a grudge against any of your people, but love your neighbor as yourself. I am the LORD.
Deut 5:10 - but showing love to a thousand generations of those who love me and keep my commandments.
Deut 6:4, 5 - Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is One. And you shall love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength.
Deut 11:1 - You shall therefore love the LORD your God and always keep His charge, His statutes, His ordinances, and His commandments.
Deut 11:13 - So if you carefully obey the commandments I am giving you today, to love the LORD your God and to serve Him with all your heart and with all your soul,
Deut 11:22 - For if you carefully keep all these commandments I am giving you to follow—to love the LORD your God, to walk in all His ways, and to hold fast to Him
Deut 13:3 - you shall not listen to the words of that prophet or that dreamer of dreams. For the LORD your God is testing you, to know whether you love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul
Deut 19:9 - because you carefully follow all these laws I command you today— to love the LORD your God and to walk always in obedience to him—then you are to set aside three more cities.
Deut 30:6 - And the LORD your God will circumcise your heart and the heart of your offspring, so that you will love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul, that you may live.
Deut 30:16 - For I am commanding you today to love the LORD your God, to walk in His ways, and to keep His commandments, statutes, and ordinances, so Biblical Theology Page 38 that you may live and increase, and the LORD your God may bless you in the land that you are entering to possess.
Deut 30:20 - and that you may love the LORD your God, obey Him, and hold fast to Him. For He is your life, and He will prolong your life in the land that the LORD swore to give to your fathers, to Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.”
Josh 22:5 - But be very careful to observe the commandment and the law that Moses the servant of the LORD gave you: to love the LORD your God, to walk in all His ways, to keep His commandments, to hold fast to Him, and to serve Him with all your heart and with all your soul.”
Josh 23:11 - So be very careful to love the LORD your God.
Matt 22:36-40 - “Teacher, which commandment is the greatest in the Law?” Jesus declared, “ ‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’ This is the first and greatest commandment. And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbour as yourself.’ All the Law and the Prophets hang on these two commandments.”
1 Cor 13:8-10 - Be indebted to no one, except to one another in love. For he who loves his neighbour has fulfilled the law. The commandments “Do not commit adultery,” “Do not murder,” “Do not steal,” “Do not covet,” and any other commandments, are summed up in this one decree: “Love your neighbor as yourself.” Love does no wrong to its neighbor. Therefore, love is the fulfillment of the law.

Thus, according to Moses, Joshua, Jesus and Paul, the old covenant law was a law of love and a matter of the heart.

Psalm 111:9 presents a few challenges in translation, particularly regarding the phrases about redemption and the covenant:

"He provided redemption for his people; he ordained his covenant forever—holy and awesome is his name." (NIV)


"He sent redemption to his people; he has commanded his covenant forever. Holy and awesome is his name!" (ESV)

The verse speaks of God’s actions in providing redemption for His people and establishing His covenant forever. However, the phrase “commanded His covenant” in some translations can feel awkward and unclear. To understand this better, let's break it down:

What does it mean for God to "command" His covenant?
The Hebrew word translated as "commanded" is צִוָּה (tzivah), which generally means "to command, to give an order." In this context, it refers to God decreeing or establishing His covenant with authority and permanence. The sense here is not merely giving an instruction but ensuring the covenant’s eternal validity and continuity.

A smoother translation could be: "He established His covenant forever," which reflects the idea of God instituting and maintaining His covenant eternally. This clarifies that God's covenant isn't just a past event but an ongoing, enduring promise.

The word for “redemption” and historical context
The Hebrew word for "redemption" used here is פְּדוּת (p'dut), which can mean "redemption" or "rescue." In historical context, this likely refers to God’s deliverance of Israel, particularly the Exodus from Egypt, which is a key example of divine rescue. Additionally, for post-exilic readers, it might evoke the return from Babylonian captivity.

The term "redemption" in this verse points to God’s ongoing pattern of intervening to rescue His people, reaffirming His covenant relationship with them.

Historical and theological context
While the psalm doesn't specify a particular act of redemption, it broadly reflects God's history of saving His people, either through the Exodus or the return from exile. These acts of deliverance demonstrate God's faithfulness to His covenant promises, ensuring that His people are continually protected and redeemed.

A better translation?
To make the verse clearer and more coherent in American English, a slightly adjusted translation might read:



"He sent rescue to His people; He established His covenant forever. Holy and awesome is His name."

This translation smooths out the phrase "commanded His covenant" to "established His covenant," making it more readable while preserving the meaning of God's eternal decree.
Conclusion
Psalm 111:9 highlights God’s active role in delivering His people and ensuring the permanence of His covenant. The word for “redemption” refers to God’s acts of rescue, such as the Exodus, and "commanded" in this context means that God has firmly established His covenant for eternity. A more coherent translation could be "He established His covenant forever," which better captures the sense of God's unchanging promise.
